# CSS Making border height accommodate content size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the border height adjust accordingly to the contents I have inside the div tags. Currently, the border values/attributes are placed in the "body CSS", but because I have many div tags in one form, I'm not sure if that's messing things up.

Just a quick note: I didn't make the CSS. Someone else made it and I have to use it for the thing I'm working on now.

```css
body{
    padding-left: 10%; 
    padding-right: 10%;
    border-style: solid; /*WHERE THE BORDER IS MADE*/
    margin: 10%;
}
#Q{
    text-align: left;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
button{
    height: 3em;
    width: 6em;
}
p.title{
    text-align: center;
}
#title{
    text-align: center;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
input, select{
    margin: 1.5%;   
}
ul{
    margin: 2%;
}
h2{
    text-align: center;   
}
.partner1{
    text-align: left;   
}
.partner2{
    text-align: right;   
}
table{
    padding: 5%;
    width: 100%;
}
th{
    text-align: center;   
}

/*
div{
    padding-left: 10%; 
    padding-right: 10%;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10%;
}*/
.page{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%; 
    padding-right: 10%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Meeting 1</h1>
<form id="meeting1" method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)" onSubmit="showValues(this)">
  <div id="page1" class="page" style="visibility:visible;">
    
    <!-- Some code here -->
    
  </div>

  <div id="page2" class="page">

    <!-- Some code here -->

  <div id="page3" class="page">
    
    <!-- Some code here -->

  </div>
</form>
```

The 3rd page's contents take up more than the display screen (in terms of height), but the border won't adjust its size to wrap up all of the contents. As a matter of fact, the border size stays the same throughout the 3 "subforms" I've created. If I place the "border-style: solid;" piece into the div CSS, it border adjusts itself, but I want to include the text that writes "Meeting 1" inside the border/box, and I don't think it's efficient to have to place "Meeting 1" in h1 tags into each of the div tags. Could someone please help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your `.page` elements are absolutely positioned, so they are out of the normal content flow, and that means that they will not affect the height of the parent container, `body` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code

```css
body{
    padding-left: 10%; 
    padding-right: 10%;
    margin: 10%;
}
#Q{
    text-align: left;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
button{
    height: 3em;
    width: 6em;
}
p.title{
    text-align: center;
}
#title{
    text-align: center;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
input, select{
    margin: 1.5%;   
}
ul{
    margin: 2%;
}
h2{
    text-align: center;   
}
.partner1{
    text-align: left;   
}
.partner2{
    text-align: right;   
}
table{
    padding: 5%;
    width: 100%;
}
th{
    text-align: center;   
}

/*
div{
    padding-left: 10%; 
    padding-right: 10%;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10%;
}*/
.page{
    position: relative;
    margin:10px;
    padding-left: 10%; 
    padding-right: 10%;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-style: solid; /*WHERE THE BORDER IS MADE*/
}

form {
    top: 35%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  
<form id="meeting1" method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)" onSubmit="showValues(this)">
  <div id="page1" class="page" style="visibility:visible;">
    
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    
  </div>

  <div id="page2" class="page" style="visibility:visible;">

    <h1>Page 2</h1></br>
    <h1>Page 2</h1></br>


  <div id="page3" class="page">
    
    <!-- Some code here -->

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, but now, the border box (along with the contents inside), are moving to different places every time I hit the "Next" button. Is there a way so that the box is at the center of the page?

Comment: Hmmm I think the problem is because I'm changing the visibilities of the divs, therefore it's just hiding the previous one and showing the next one. I'll try to figure this out. Thank you so much for your help, **VVK**!!